# Error with NDSolve in EDOs

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to numerically solve a system of ODEs

```
\[CapitalRho] = 2 10 ^-6

\[CapitalDelta] = 10 ^-14
\[ScriptCapitalC] = 0.4955 51554



system1 = {\[ScriptC]'[
 t] == -3 (\[ScriptJ][t]/\[CapitalRho]), \[ScriptQ]'[
 t] == ((-30 \[CapitalDelta] \[ScriptQ][
      t])/\[CapitalRho]^2) - (45 \[ScriptJ][
     t]/(2 \[CapitalRho]^2)), ((35 \[CapitalDelta] (\
\[ScriptCapitalC] - \[ScriptC][
       t]))/\[CapitalRho]) == (8 \[CapitalDelta] \[ScriptQ][
    t]) - \[ScriptJ][t]};
initials = {\[ScriptC][0] == 25545, \[ScriptQ][0] == 
0, \[ScriptJ][0] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[{system1,initials}, {\[ScriptC][t], \[ScriptQ][t], \[ScriptJ][t]}, {t, 0,3000}]
```

when I run the code I get the following errors:

```
NDSolve::nlnum: The function value {0.,0.,0. +(35 (-25545.+\[ScriptCapitalC]) \[CapitalDelta])/\[CapitalRho]} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {3} at {t,\[ScriptC][t],\[ScriptJ][t],\[ScriptQ][t],(\[ScriptC]^\[Prime])[t],(\[ScriptJ]^\[Prime])[t],(\[ScriptQ]^\[Prime])[t]} = {0.,25545.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.}.

NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.
```

I tried to fix the errors but I didn't succussed, does anyone know how to fix the code to make it all work?

Comment: `0.4955 51554` means `0.4955 * 51554` or roughly about `25545` -- is that what you want? Or did you mean `0.495551554`, a number slightly less than 1/2?

Comment: Note that if `0.4955 * 51554`, then setting the first of the initials to `25545.007` is what will satisfy the residual function. It also leads to constant solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"MassMatrix"}`

```
Ρ = 2 10^-6;
Δ = 10^-14;
\[ScriptCapitalC] = 0.4955*51554;

system1 = {\[ScriptC]'[
     t] == -3 (\[ScriptJ][t]/Ρ), \[ScriptQ]'[
     t] == ((-30*Δ*\[ScriptQ][
          t])/Ρ^2) - (45 \[ScriptJ][
         t]/(2*Ρ^2)), ((35*Δ*(\
\[ScriptCapitalC] - \[ScriptC][
           t]))/Ρ) == (8*Δ*\[ScriptQ][
        t]) - \[ScriptJ][t]};

initials = {\[ScriptC][0] == 25545, \[ScriptQ][0] == 
    0, \[ScriptJ][0] == 0};

sol=NDSolve[{system1,initials},{\[ScriptC],\[ScriptQ],\[ScriptJ]},{t,0,3000},
    Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"MassMatrix"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[Link to notebook](https://12000.org/tmp/01132024/A.nb)  (since your code is hard to format here)

Screen shot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

V 13.3.1

Reference https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to address this is to eliminate `j[t]` from the system. It can easily be solved for in terms of the other two functions. Then you have more robust methods available to `NDSolve`. Even more, it's a simple linear system without `j[t]`. You could even use `DSolve` and get an exact solution. It's also easier on others if you don't post in strange glyphs.

```
(* with script C rationalized to 25545007/1000 *)
system1 = {Derivative[1][c][t] == -1500000  j[t], 
   Derivative[1][q][t] == -5625000000000  j[t] - (3 q[t])/40, (
    7 (25545007/1000 - c[t]))/40000000 == -j[t] + q[t]/12500000000000};

initials = {c[0] == 25545007/1000, q[0] == 0, j[0] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[{List @@ Eliminate[system1, j[t]], initials}, {c, 
    q}, {t, 0, 3000}];
sol = Join[sol, Solve[system1[[3]], j[t]] /. First@sol, 2];

Through[{c, q, j}[t]] // Map[
   Block[{c, q, j},
     Evaluate@
       Through[{c, q, j}[t_]] = (Through[{c, q, j}[t]] /. First@sol); 
     Plot[#, {t, 0, 3000}, PlotLabel -> HoldForm[#]]
     ] &] // GraphicsRow[#, ImageSize -> 800] &
```

[image]

If we solve for stationary points, we see they're the same as the initial condition above:

```
Solve[system1 /. {c'[t] | q'[t] -> 0}, {c[t], q[t]}, {j[t]}]

(* {{c[t] -> 25545007/1000, q[t] -> 0}} *)
```

Note that `25545.007` prints out in the front end as `25545`, so I assumed `25545.007` was meant.
If the OP meant `25545` and not `25545.007`, then `j` is not zero at the initial condition (`initials` in the OP are inconsistent with the 3rd equation in `system1`). For `c[0]` equal to `25545` at `t == 0`, we get an nontrivial solution, just by changing the `initials` above.